# Why isn't writing the ISO image to my USB flash drive working?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, xubuntu, usb-creator

I have a 8GB flash drive, and another 1GB flash drive that contains an ISO file of Xubuntu 12.04. I am trying to write this ISO image on to my 8GB drive, so that I can boot into it and install Xubuntu on my hard drive.

Currently, I am running the same Xubuntu version from a Live CD -- I messed up while writing so I can't install it using the CD.

My HDD is empty, there is no OS on it yet.

I have tried both using dd to write the image, however when I boot nothing happens -- just a white cursor blinks. I also tried the same with UNetbootin, however I get the same result. No splash screens or other messages appear, just the cursor when booting from the flash drive. It's not an issue with my drive/BIOS as I've written images to it before (on Windows). Both of these were written on the drive with a freshly-formatted NTFS partition.

Does anyone know any tools that will do this successfully, or know how I can solve the blinking cursor issue?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> *Both of these were written on the drive with a freshly-formatted NTFS partition.*

Your problem is **you are formatting the USB as NTFS**. Ubuntu cannot boot from an NTFS partition.

Please format the USB stick as FAT (or FAT32) instead. Then use Unetbootin (not Windows dd) to "burn" the ISO to the USB and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will work but

Boot to live CD then copy the ISO to the desktop then just use the live usb creator to copy it to the new USB.

Answer (score 0):

I think ISO master should work, there is a post which says that it worked by making an iso image and adding boot information in it.